# Not able to read a characteristic value from BLE device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, gatt

I need to write and read a characteristic value to Android BLE device. I'm able to write but not read. Here is how I'm writing :

```
public void writeCustomCharacteristic(int value) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    /*check if the service is available on the device*/
    BluetoothGattService mCustomService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("<MY SERVICE UUID>"));
    if(mCustomService == null){
        Log.w(TAG, "Custom BLE Service not found");
        return;
    }
    /*get the read characteristic from the service*/
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic mWriteCharacteristic = mCustomService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("<MY CHARACTERSTIC UUID>"));
   mWriteCharacteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
       mWriteCharacteristic.setValue(value,BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8,0);
    if(!mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mWriteCharacteristic)){
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to write characteristic");
    }else{
        Log.w(TAG, "Success to write characteristic");
    }
}
```

And this operation is success if I use

```
 mWriteCharacteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
```

If I use any other write types rather than `WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE` then it is not triggering `onCharacteristicWrite()` callback method.

Here is how I'm reading the characteristic :

```
 private boolean readCharacteristics(int groupPosition,int childPosition){
    try{
        if (mGattCharacteristics != null) {
            final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = mGattCharacteristics.get(2).get(2);
            final int charaProp = characteristic.getProperties();
            if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) > 0) {
                // If there is an active notification on a characteristic, clear
                // it first so it doesn't update the data field on the user interface.
                if (mNotifyCharacteristic != null) {
                    mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(mNotifyCharacteristic, false);
                    mNotifyCharacteristic = null;
                }
                mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
            }
            if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0) {
                mNotifyCharacteristic = characteristic;
                mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
            }
            waitSometime(100);
            if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_INDICATE) > 0) {
                mNotifyCharacteristic = characteristic;
                mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicIndication(characteristic, true);
            }
            waitSometime(100);
            if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE) > 0) {

                byte[] value = characteristic.getValue(); //this is being NULL always

                if (mNotifyCharacteristic != null) {
                    mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(mNotifyCharacteristic, true);
                    mNotifyCharacteristic = null;
                }
                mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(characteristic, value);
                if(value!=null&&value.length>0) {
                    Toast.makeText(DeviceControlActivity.this,"success reading data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                  Toast.makeText(DeviceControlActivity.this,"error reading data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
       /* if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_INDICATE) > 0) {
            mNotifyCharacteristic = characteristic;
            //characteristic.setWriteType();
            mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicIndication(
                    characteristic, true);
            byte[] value=characteristic.getValue();
        }*/
            return true;
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

`characteristic.getValue()` returns always null. Where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You incorrectly use bitor instead of bitand. Also, don't sleep and then expect the value to have been read. Instead wait for the callback that tells when the read has completed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my opinion:

You need to figure out what kind of characteristic you are going to get data? Some of them need to set indication or notify first! Like:

a. Get the descriptor of the characteristic

```
   BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = gattCharacteristic.getDescriptors().get(0); 
     //Usually is Client_Characteristic_Configuration
```

b. According to the characteristic, set the property() of descriptor true.

```
if ((gattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY)> 0 ){
    if (descriptor != null) {
       descriptor.setValue((BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE));
       }
   }
else if((gattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_INDICATE) >0 ){
    if(descriptor != null){
       descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
       }
   }
```

c. Send the value to the remote BLE device.

```
gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

After that, you may get the data in callback function:

```
onCharacteristicChanged
```

At least above work for me!
Hope can help someone~